# Optimizing .NET core microservice project structure

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I trying to develop Microservice in .Net core.
planning to implement project structure like

```
Frontend
Services
 -Product
   -Product.Api
   -Product.Application
   -Product.Domain
   -Product.Infrastructure

 -Basket
   -Basket.Api
   -Basket.Application
   -Basket.Domain
   -Basket.Infrastructure

 -Order
   -Order.Api
   -Order.Application
   -Order.Domain
   -Order.Infrastructure
```

In the above project structure, under service folder currently three module(Product, Basket and Order). many module will added later.

Where each module have 4 projects for Api, Application ,Domain, Infrastructure. if add more module increase number of class library and web project. this will drop Visual studio loading, compile and running time of project due to my hardware is not enough.

Please recommend any other pattern for optimizing number of projects in the microservice?

Answer (score 2):

If the number of class libraries is the determining factor in your architecture performance, maybe it is time to converge the modules into the same module.

If it is absolutely necessary to continue using the microservice architecture and the high number of modules, you should consider investing in more powerful hardware.

Developing software often requires a lot of ram to house all the processes running the stack locally.

Another approach would be to try to develop on a cloud platform such as Azure, and use the corresponding tools to debug against a cloud instance or even in a GitHub Codespace.

Answer (score 1):

If Product, Basket and Order are different microservices, then they should be in different Visual Studio solutions. Each solution will be small and independent and they'll all load and work fast regardless of how many microservices you have.

If Product, Basket and Order are part of the same microservice and you are planning to add many more modules, your microservice design is probably wrong, as a single microservice appears to have far too many responsibilities. In this case, the solution is to limit the responsibilities of each microservice so that they don't grow to enormous sizes.

If what you are building is a modular monolith (a single deployable unit, but with the code organised in modules), then the solutions are a bit different. If it's a single developer application, you probably don't need to split the modules in separate projects. For example, the whole API can be a single project and each module be in a different folder. If there'll be many developers and teams working on the source code, then you might want to create a separate solution for each module, so each team can work on their own code.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.
Product ,Basket and order is different microservice. They will develop based on the DDD and CQRS patterns. it's decided based on the intercommunication and scenario. Above scenario completely hypothetical. If simple CRUD Operation we go with REST web API with CRUD operation using repository pattern. I'm completely new to microservice. I try to develop initial architecture.

Comment: OK. Then if they are separate microservices, ideally their code would be in different VS solutions (potentially different source code repositories), so you won't have the VS size problem that you mention.

Comment: Thanks Francesc for your valuable feedback.

Comment: @FrancescCastells microservices doesn't necessarily mean alone solution/repo 
microservices is 100% decupled behavioral/architectural wise not development wise. 
It could be deferent repos and solutions with different teams. BUT not NECESSARLTY. 
take Microsoft's "Eshop on containers"  sorry man but there are some overengineering in your answer.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada eShopOnContainers is not a real world sample. Implementing such a small system in microservices is definitely overengineering. The OP is worried about its VS being too slow when the system is very large, with many modules, which would be a more realistic scenario. In that scenario, you obviously separate them in different solutions. The benefits of microservices are to be able to develop and run them independently. If you develop them together to the point that your VS solution is too slow you are completely defeating the point of microservices.

Comment: @FrancescCastells So having multiple vs instances running on his local machine will optimize the performance? Eshop on containers is not real word but it coverd so many aspects

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada You don't have to run multiple VS instances on the local machine.  You are focussing on a sample project that is far from real life. In a real life microservices scenario, the actual point of the microservices is to be able to develop and run them independently. This means that you don't need to run all the microservices in your local machine in order to develop and test them. If you do, then it's not a microservices architecture, it's a distributed monolith. Again,if your scenario is a tiny project, then you don't have a VS performance problem and it's not what the OP is asking

Comment: @FrancescCastells, I'm taking specifically about this question . 
the guy is saying that there is issue with loading all those projects imagine of there were multiple solutions

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada you keep missing the point. If the system is big (many modules and projects), they should be in different solutions. That is the point of microservices, to break down a big system into smaller, more manajeable parts (independent and faster development, testing, deployment, scaling, etc). If you keep developing all microservices together, why are you even doing microservices?

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada as I said before... you keep missing the point. If the system is so large with so many microservices that your VS is too slow and you need to buy a larger computer, then "necessarily" you have to split the solution. It really is the point of microservices. To break down a large system into smaller more workable ones. I don't know how else to explain it. I'll add a comment to your answer, which is incorrect and misleading. Also, moderate your tone in your comments.

Comment: @FrancescCastells , Microsoft also referring eShopOnContainers  in the following URL : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/introduce-eshoponcontainers-reference-app)

This sample also everything in single project . if take basket project , no separate class library project for keeping repository in Infrastructure every thing in separated by folder structure. Are you sure [link](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) is a perfect project?

I'm referring this documentation for development.

Comment: @Justcode, eShopOnContainers is definitely not a perfect project (I actually advised against taking it as a guideline). This project is just a way to showcase many different technologies and strategies for microservices in a solution as small as possible. In real life, that set up is not realistic. You might have some low importance microservices coded this way (with everything in one or two projects), but important microservices will likely contain multiple projects and be in their own solution.

Comment: eShopOnContainers  is the boilerplate microservers architecture project byMicrosoft.  but you don't have to copy it to its full details. 
you need to understand not imitate. take the best of each world. in  architecture  world its all about trade offs. 
@FrancescCastells said some valid points. but there is no right or wrong here. 
you decide. after understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Like @abo said: if the number of assemblies in impacting the performance of your application consider one assembly per module.

If your driver for having multiple assemblies per module was governance on dependencies then consider using an additional tool like https://github.com/realvizu/NsDepCop which allows you to enforce architectural/dependency rules without the help of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

well,
I have some notes on this Architecture you are making.
if you do it right the one of the payoff is going to be less impact on the hardware.

**note#1 :** make A Kernel Module which has all of the abstraction of the common  functionalities. (that other microservices and take a reference from).  like the base repository, message queue base handler ,command /command handler. and u you want to disconnect a module from the kernel you can do that and add your own abstractions alone in that module (simplicity is the ultimate sophistication).

**note#2 :** Not every module needs to have the same projects or layers as u putting for example: -generally speaking- Basket doesn't need infrastructure. all it does to tell the order module if there is any order on going or pending for this user.

**note#3 :** microservices is notorious of needing a high-end server to handle the massive amount of nodes/application.

finally I have an awesome blueprint for you to study and follow.
which happens to covers the same case youre after.

here is the [link](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)

Comment: note #3 is the opposite of what microservices are meant to be. Microservices are meant to break down a large system into smaller ones, which are easier to work with. You shouldn't need to run all your microservices at once in a single machine, specially during development. The example in note #2 makes a large assumption with the Basket microservice functionality. It's very unlikely that a microservice doesn't need any infrastructure code. note #1 having common infrastructure code won't remove the need for concrete infrastructure code, so this approach won't reduce the number of projects.

Comment: lol , dont take it personal son. every thing is crystal clear. "pposite of what microservices" you say event sourcing and loggin alone needs detected servers.
at this point you are just arguing. peace...